# activator ui show Waiting for sbt server to restart and Lost or failed sbt connection: Operation timed out

Tags: playframework-2.5

[image]

[image]

Activator ui view always waiting for sbt server to restart 
and Build view always output `lost or failed sbt connection: Operation timed out`

Answer (score 1):

Following is only the beginning of an answer.  I've been researching a nearly identical problem, and it sounds like Activator uses an sbt plugin called [sbt-remote-control](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control/) for restarting the sbt server.  I have not yet located where this plugin is called from Activator, but suspect something in this plugin is timing out, either due to a default or to an argument passed from Activator.

[Activator FAQ](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/docs) says you can add a line to ~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt to lengthen a timeout, but I followed the suggestion and that did not resolve the problem for me. (I also found I had to create the activatorconfig.txt file for my installation.)

Security configuration may also be a factor.  My version of this issue occurs on a corporate Win7 laptop with high security lockdown, but not on another personal Win7 laptop.